# default values and variable scope

Tags: lua, scope, default-value

I think I am missing something about how variable scopes and or default value work lua. Consider the following function:

```
function printtable(x, indentation_level)

   indentation_level = indentation_level or 0

   function indent()
      dent = ''
      for i=1,indentation_level do
         dent = dent..'__'
      end
      return dent
   end

   if type(x) ~= 'table' then
      return tostring(x)
   end

   rpr = ''
   for k, v in pairs(x) do
      rpr = rpr..indent()..'['..printtable(k)..']'..' = '..printtable(v, indentation_level+1)
   end
   return rpr
end
```

when I invoke it with

```
t = {1,2,3}

print(printtable(t))
```

I will get `[1] = 1__[2] = 2__[3] = 3`

What I expected is `[1] = 1[2] = 2[3] = 3`

I rewrote the function in python to see where my logic error is:

```
def printdict(x, indentation_level=0):

    def indent():

        dent = ''
        for i in range(indentation_level):
            dent += '__'
        return dent

    if type(x) != dict:
        return str(x)

    rpr = ''
    for k, v in x.items():
        rpr = rpr+indent()+'['+printdict(k)+'] = '+printdict(v, indentation_level+1)

    return rpr
```

And when I invoke it with:

```
t = {1:1,2:2,3:3}

print(printdict(t))
```

I get what I would expect: `[1] = 1[2] = 2[3] = 3`

So, what is going on with the lua version? What am I missing about variable scope or some other mechanic that causes the difference?

Comment: you're missing a local infront of function indent

Comment: I recommend this reading: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ScopeTutorial

Comment: Tried again, with local function.   Works as expected. Never mind.  You should also probably make the dent value local in the indent function.

Comment: @WilliamWalsh (This is either language lawyering or something you might not know.)  Only variables are local or global; Values, including functions, don't have a scope. `local function` is the syntax for a statement that 1) creates a local variable and then 2) evaluates a function definition to obtain a function value and assigns it to the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should declare `indent`, `dent`, `rpr`, and probably `printtable` to be `local`. (Unlike Python, Lua requires us to declare our variables to specify their scope. Parameters and looping variables are automatically local to the block that defines them.)

The problem is caused by `indent` being global.

Note that `indentation_level` is local to `printtable` because it's a parameter. `indent` makes reference to `indentation_level`, which means that `indent` is a **closure**. A closure is a function that stores a reference to an outer local variable.

Every time you call `printtable`, it defines a new incarnation of `indent` with whatever `indentation_level` was in scope at the time. In your code, `indent` is a global variable, so every new definition of `indent` overwrites the previous one.

In this loop:

```
for k, v in pairs(x) do
  rpr = rpr..indent()..'['..printtable(k)..']'..' = '..printtable(v, indentation_level+1)
end
```

...you call `printtable`, which defines `indent` with an `indentation_level` of 1. This is the `indent` that gets called on every iteration after the first.

Note that your input table has no subtables, so the recursion only goes down one level. That loop only runs in the initial call. That's why `indentation_level` is never higher than 1 (which makes sense for what you're trying to do).

You can fix this by making `indent` `local`.

Comment: Okay, I see.. kind of. But I don't really understand what happens yet. Does `indent` get defined every time `printtable` is called when it is not set to local? I would expect the indentation to increase a second time when I call printtable twice in the loop: `rpr = rpr..indent()..'['..printtable(k, indentation_level+1)..']'..' = '..printtable(v, indentation_level+1)` but it does not.

Comment: @lotolmencre: Edited to hopefully explain it better.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua, variables are "global by default." If there is no local (including parameters) "above" the use of a variable, it is bound to the global environment. If there is, it bound to the closest one above.